# How to put up new content some part of a div is pressed

Tags: html, django, frontend

The title is probably confusing but there isnt a better way to ask the question.
Im making a job searching website using django. Im not really experienced in the front end. I want a list of job offers to be showing and when one of them is clicked I want a enlarged version with additional info(Apply button, detailed description) to appear of the specific job offer clicked. Sort of like how it linkedin does it. This is the code I am using for listing out all of the jobs.

I know I will probably need a dynamic url but from there I dont know how to implement it on the front end. Comps is just a list of all of the objects in a Model for Companies.

```
{% for comp in comps %}

    <div class="CompList">
        <span>{{comp.jtitle}}</span>
        <h2>{{comp.name}}</h2>
        <h3>{{comp.country}}, {{comp.city}}</h3>
    </div>


{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you lookign for is called `Accordion` to which you find many tutorials using JS or "CSS-Hacks".

However less know are the `<details>`- and `<summary>`-tags you can use to accomplish this with pure HTML.

`details` wraps all the title and the description while `summary` will eb the visible title. As soon as you click it, it will expand and also show the rest:

```css
/* CSS only for viszualisation purpose */
details {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 10px;
}

summary {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Job Title</summary>
  <p>Long job description<br>
    can be added<br>
    right after the<br>
    summary tag</p>
</details>
```